# Powershell: mandatory parameter specification ignored

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script where I specify two mandatory and one optional parameters like so:

```
Param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
  [string]$filePath,

 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] 
  [string]$searchbase,

 [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]  
  [int]$restartService=0
)
```

When I run the script, nothing at all happens, whether or not I specify a parameter. Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: What do you mean "nothing at all happens"? Can you create a small reproducing case to post?

Comment: It's hard to guess without seeing whole script, but behavior suggest one thing: you defined a function within a script, and param block you've shared is a part of this function. Your script doesn't call the function, so parameters are not used...

Comment: <<facepalm>>.
Thanks, BartekB